# NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray object in object

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm smashing my head with a `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` add objects for keys stuff.

I got 2 mutable arrays and I want to combine them.

**NSMutableArray 1** :

```
 {
        email = "a@a1.com";
        "password" = "2017-05-23 13:08:03";
    }
```

**NSMutableArray 2**

```
(
        {
        "created_at" = "2017-06-22 00:00:00";
        "id_weather_city" = 1;
        name = Cityname;
        "updated_at" = "2017-06-22 00:00:00";
    },
        {
        "created_at" = "2017-06-22 00:00:00";
        "id_weather_city" = 2;
        name = Cityname2;
        "updated_at" = "2017-06-22 00:00:00";
    }
)
```

I want to combine them together like this, but I don't know how
right array :

```
{
    email = "a@a1.com";
    "password" = "2017-05-23 13:08:03";
    "weather":(
        {
        "created_at" = "2017-06-22 00:00:00";
        "id_weather_city" = 1;
        name = Cityname;
        "updated_at" = "2017-06-22 00:00:00";
    },
        {
        "created_at" = "2017-06-22 00:00:00";
        "id_weather_city" = 2;
        name = Cityname2;
        "updated_at" = "2017-06-22 00:00:00";
    }
)
}
```

Comment: Can share what you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one isn't an array, it's a dictionary. Knowing that you can do

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [item1 mutableCopy];
dict[@"weather"] = [item2 copy];
```

Simply copy the first dictionary, and insert the second one for `weather` key

Comment: Thank you, i forgot that i can add an object using dict[@"name"]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
NSMutableDictionary *finalDictionary =  [[array1 objectAtIndex : 0] mutableCopy];
[finalDictionary setValue : array2 forKey:@"weather"];
```